# Error returning a user defined class Object on RestApi call using Jax-Rs

Tags: java, api, jax-rs

Can any one help me in returning the user defined class objects using rest apis.
That is on successful rest api call, return a user object.
I tried this

```java
@Path("/login")
@GET
//@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public User login(@QueryParam("username") String username, 
        @QueryParam("password") String password, 
        @QueryParam("org") String org)
{
    CometAppStack cs= new CometAppStack();
    User user= cs.loginUser(username, password, org);
    return user;
}
```

but getting an error saying

> wrong number of arguments

Please help me.

Comment: Is that a compile-time error? Which line is causing it?

Comment: That can't literally be the error message. Where's the rest of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems alright, except you should un comment the line:
@Produces

also if you can provide some more info of the code or configuration that will help.

at what point the error is coming ?

make sure you are calling the uri correctly and the names should match 
like:

https://hostname:port/login?**username**=abc&**password**=xyz&**org**=org